# Expression based value for @ImportResource

Tags: java, spring

I'm using spring boot with @ImportResource and I was wondering if there's any way to indicate a bunch of files based on their name expression. For example:

```
@ImportResource(value = {"classpath:/application-data-api-spring.xml", "classpath:/application-service-api-spring.xml"}
```

Should be replaced with something like:

```
@ImportResource(value = {"classpath:/application-*-api-spring.xml"}
```